# no unique solution - linear equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I am asking myself:

How can I show that a linear equation $xm + yn = z$, for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$, cannot have a unique solution $(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: One way to see this is by taking $\pmod{m}$.

Comment: Maybe you can use the notion that the equation can be "simplified" as the following... $(x+n)(y+m)=z+yx+nm$

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions if these is one solution. let $x_0, y_0$ be the unique solution of $mx_0+ny_0=z$. Then
there are infintely many solutuins  given as $$x=x_0+nj,~ y=y_0-jm,~ j \in Z.$$
Or no solution if $x_0, y_0$ do not exist.

Comment: But doesn't there either exist infinitely many solutions or no solution?

Comment: @Tithus248 Yes you are right, See my edit now.